# Lateral thinking in a field of cows

Tags: lateral-thinking, wordplay

Been a little riddle currently going around the family. Is really easy but one to try out on your friends and family.

> There are **40 cows** in a field and **28 chickens**.
>   How many didn't?

Hope you all enjoyed.

Comment: What on Earth o.O

Comment: what kind of family do you have? :o

Comment: A strange yet lovely family ;)

Comment: I suppose I should point out that riddles must first go on the riddle sandbox. Related meta post: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5276/25860

Comment: Ordinarily done with wolves and sheep.

Comment: This reminds me of that old joke: "What's the difference between a duck?"
To which the answer is:
"One leg is both the same!"

Comment: Makes MUCH more sense with wolves and sheep.

Comment: @Shufflepants I'm still trying to understand what you said..

Comment: @maxathousand I think that's supposed to be the joke. It's words that are grammatically correct, and sound like they might mean something, but they make no sense at all.

Comment: @Shufflepants okay, good--I felt pretty dumb.

Comment: @Shufflepants The way I've heard it was: "What's the difference between a duck? -It swims better than it walks" (Which even makes some sense)

Comment: @Marius, a better question might be "what kind of *cows* do you have?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this right?

> The answer is 20 I think

Reason:

> 40 cows in a field twenty 8 chickens 
>  20 ate chickens 
>  How many didn't? the other 20.
>  
>  It's all a play on the sounds of the words, more than the words themselves... I came to this thought due to the lateral thinking. y'know... it's not what it seems originally.

Comment: Huh for some reason, the original accepted answer has disappeared. It did say the same thing as your current answer

Comment: Strange. Maybe they deleted it?

Comment: probably, it's weird though. Also somehow Stack Exchange thinks 20-6=15

Comment: Yeah, this is right. Have marked you for it :D

Comment: Awesome :D Rep Whore Jake is on a roll ;)

Answer (score 14):

The answer is:

> 39

Because:

> Twenty-eight is a name (number) of a cow, so there is one cow that chickens. A moment later you ask how many cows did not chicken. The answer is thirty-nine.

---

Another option, if you expect the person saying the riddle is poor at English:

> 12

Because:

> Twenty-eight cows chicken. A moment later you can ask how many cows did not chicken. The answer is, the other ones than the twenty-eight, which is twelve.

Comment: Pray tell, what does it mean for a cow to chicken?

Comment: This is almost better than the answer ;-)

Comment: @immibis unless you're being sarcastic, to chicken means to back out of something because you're scared

Answer (score -1):

The Answer is

> 40

Because,

> Cows don't eat chicken.

Comment: It's tagged lateral-thinking for a reason

Comment: @Mukesh Really? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9vxHN8_jSE